# display array values in view using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

**Controller:**

```
function checkedServices() {

        $data = array();
        foreach($this->input->post('check_service') as $ser) {
            $data[] = array('service' => $ser);
        }

        $checked_services['services'] = array($data);

        $this->load->view('checked_services', $checked_services);
    }
```

**view:**

```
foreach($services as $ser)
    {   
        echo $ser;
    }
```

**Output:**

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: views/checked_services.php

Comment: You should modify your controller. It's complicated.

Comment: you have added an array so you need to include one more foreach loop for $user in view

Comment: no need to wrap one more array this `array($data);` in controller, simply assign `$checked_services['services'] = $data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Controller**

```
function checkedServices() 
{

        $data = array();
        foreach($this->input->post('check_service') as $ser) {
            $data[]['service'] = $ser;
        }

        $checked_services['services'] = $data;

        $this->load->view('checked_services', $checked_services);
    }
```

**In View**

```
foreach($services as $ser)
{
  echo $ser['service'];
}
```

Comment: You're Welcome. Happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

$data is array

```
$checked_services['services'] = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a simple code complex.

Just remove `array` from this statement.

```
$checked_services['services'] = $data;
```

In your controller, you are looping and getting data in `$data`.

`$data` is already an array, why do you want `array($data)`?

Comment: I think he also need to change this line

`foreach($this->input->post('check_service') as $ser) {
 $data[] = array('service' => $ser);
}`

to

`foreach($this->input->post('check_service') as $ser) {
 $data[] = $ser;
}`

Comment: Thanks for response.I want that user should be able to see that what services he has selected. When I use print_r(services);, all the services are printed but in an array form not normal form

Comment: If its array, loop over it using foreach. You will get the solution.

Comment: I changed $checked_services['services'] = array($data); to $checked_services['services'] = $data;.. then I used print_r($services); on view it printed all the values but in array format